# Python 2.7 create new line for record in csv(unicodecsv)

Tags: python, csv

I currently have a list of data containing these properties:

```
properties = {
                'address':address,
                'city':city,
                'state':state,
                'postal_code':postal_code,
                'price':price,
                'facts and features':info,
                'real estate provider':broker,
                'url':property_url,
                'title':title
                        }
```

These are populated with about 25 rows.
I am attempting to write them to a csv file using this:

```
                with open("ogtest-%s-%s.csv" % (listValue, zipCodes),'w') as csvfile:
                fieldnames = ['title','address','city','state','postal_code','price','facts and features','real estate provider','url']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                for row in scraped_data:
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

my end csv result is a list with the data in one row.  Each area such as address has title and below it ALL the values.  [image]

['/profile/Colin-Welman/', '/profile/andreagressinger/', '/profile/Regina-Vannicola/', '/profile/Kathryn-Perkins/', etc

The scraped_data appears like this:
{'city': '(844) 292-5128(310) 505-7493(310) 562-8483(310) 422-9001(310) 439-5303(323) 736-4891(310) 383-8111(310) 482-2033(646) 872-4990(310) 963-1648', 'state': None, 'postal_code': None, 'facts and features': u'', 'address': ['/profile/Jonathan-Pearson/', '/profile/margret2/', '/profile/user89580694/', '/profile/Rinde-Philippe/', '/profile/RogerPerryLA/', '/profile/tamaramattox/', '/profile/JFKdogtownrealty/', '/profile/The-Cunningham-Group/', '/profile/TheHeatherGroup/', '/profile/EitanSeanConstine1/'], 'url': None, 'title': None, 'price': None, 'real estate provider': 'Jonathan PearsonMargret EricksonSusan & Rachael RosalesRinde PhilippeRoger PerryTamara Mattoxjeff koneckeThe Cunningham GroupHeather Shawver & Heather RogersEitan Sean Constine'}

My goal is for each item to be on it's own row.
I've tried this: adding 'newline' in the with open (it gives an error)
adding delimiter to csv.Dictwriter (this added individual columns for each record not rows)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is confusing. First, you say your end result is a list with all the data in one _column_, but what you show us looks like a single _row_. Also, is that actually copied and pasted from the resulting CSV file? Because if so, it looks like you may have elements of your dicts that are lists—that's the only obvious way you're going to get quoted strings inside brackets like that.

Comment: More generally: Please show us the actual `scraped_data` (or, better yet, a stripped-down version with only, say, two rows), and the same for the CSV file, and the expected version of the CSV file that you're not getting. That way, you don't have to explain it in words, we can just see it.

Comment: You don't have an issue with within this code. 
Try `print (scraped_data[0]) `you'll  see the issue there. Your data is not being properly parsed. Take care!

Comment: @abarnert I've added the scraped_data.  I've also correct it where I said it appears in one column.  You are right it should have said one row.

Comment: @Elvir Muslic I've added how scraped_data appears.  How should it be parsed?

Comment: Well, there's your problem: the scraped data is a single dict, which includes such fun things as a list of addresses in the `address` field, and a bunch of phone numbers concatenated together with no delimiters into one big string in the `city` field, and a bunch of names similarly concatenated in the `real estate provider` field, and so on. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Where does this scraped data come from? If you're scraping it wrong, that's what you need to fix, not this code. If you're stuck with this data, you need to figure out what it's supposed to mean before you can write code to parse it. Maybe you can un-concatenate the phone numbers (fixed format?) and maybe even the names (everyone has 2 names, properly capitalized, and no McFly?), and then zip together all the lists and concatenated lists (hopefully same length?), although you can't recover stuff like whatever was supposed to be in `city` and isn't here at all…

Comment: @abarnert I gave pbo the answer cause he submitted it as an answer but you and Elvir were right on.  I was going over the area once and putting all the data in one list together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scraped_data` should be a list of dictionaries for `csv.DictWriter` to work. For instance:

```
import csv 

# mock data
scraped_data = list()
row = {
    'title': 'My Sweet Home',
    'address': '1000, Abc St.',
    'city': 'San Diego',
    'facts and features': 'Miniramp in the backyard',
    'postal_code': '000000',
    'price': 1000000,
    'real estate provider': 'Abc Real Estate',
    'state': 'CA',
    'url': 'www.mysweethome.com'
}
scraped_data.append(row)

fieldnames = [
    'title', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'price', 
    'facts and features', 'real estate provider', 'url'
]

# writing CSV file
with open('ogtest.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in scraped_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers